# Jetpack Compose back button press in automation test

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-testing

What is the recommended way to **trigger a back button press in a jetpack compose test** (running on a real device)?

I'm trying:

```
@get:Rule()
val composeTestRule = createAndroidComposeRule(MyActivity::class.java)

@Test
fun test() {
    // Here would be some setup code, assertions and navigating into a second screen
     
    // Navigate back to previous screen
    composeTestRule.onRoot().performKeyPress(KeyEvent(NativeKeyEvent(0, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)))

    // continue... 
}
```

But I get the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: KeyEvent can't be processed because this key input node is not active.
```

I don't have any special logic for the key presses / navigation and only use out-of-the box functionality of the navigation compose library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use below code to test device back button from composable screen

```
Espresso.pressBack()
```

Comment: Works and is so much cleaner. Thanks! Don't know how I missed this one.

Comment: Keep in mind, this solution doesn't work on Firebase Test labs (Tested on Pixel 5 physical device).
@OliverMetz's solution works in all the cases.

Comment: Espresso.pressBack causing multiple issues

Answer (score 9):

I ended up using the ActivityScenarioRule:

```
composeTestRule.activityRule.scenario.onActivity { activity ->
   activity.onBackPressedDispatcher.onBackPressed()
}
```

Not sure if this is the right way to do it but it works.

EDIT: As pointed out correctly by LN-12 you should be using the `onBackPressedDispatcher` to support [API 33's predictive back gestures](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/predictive-back-gesture).

Comment: `activity.onBackPressed()` is deprecated. You should now use `activity.onBackPressedDispatcher.onBackPressed()`.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
composeTestRule.onAllNodes(isRoot())[0].performKeyPress(
            KeyEvent(
                android.view.KeyEvent(
                    android.view.KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN,
                    android.view.KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK
                )
            )
        )
```